# Exchange Content between Local and Production

Tags: content

Often I want to test in my local environment with content other people created on the production site. So it would be great to copy e.g. an entry from production.

I've found:

- Smith https://plugins.craftcms.com/smith for copy, pasting, and cloning of matrix blocks, but *unfortunately* only within one Craft installation.

**Is there a smart way to quickly exchange content from production with a local dev environment and vise versa?**

Comment: I looking at exactly the same issue. Sorry when I find out i'll come back to you.
\

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at this article and the scripts introduced there. It basically gives you a console command that pulls the live database or assets into your local environment.

https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms

The article was written before the project config feature was a thing as far as I know. So watch out for that.